# リストの中からアナグラムの単語同士を見つけるプログラムを作りたい

Tags: python

リスト内でアナグラム同士を見つけたいのですが、実行すると以下の様に同じ内容が繰り返し表示されてしまいます。どのように変更すればいいですか？

**実行結果**

```
iceman cinema
iceman cinema
.
.
.
```

**現状のプログラム**

```
def anagram(anagram_list):
    for i in anagram_list:
        for j in anagram_list:
            i=0
            j=1
            a=anagram_list[i]
            b=anagram_list[j]
            a=a.lower()
            b=b.lower()
            if sorted(a)==sorted(b):
                print(a,b)
            elif sorted(a)!=sorted(b):
                continue
            i+=1
            j+=1
list=["iceman","cinema","leaf","tree","live","Evil","Silent","listen","good","god"]
anagram(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.combinations()` を使ってみてはどうでしょうか。

```
from itertools import combinations

def anagram(lst):
  for (a, b) in combinations(lst, 2):
    if sorted(a.lower()) == sorted(b.lower()):
      print(a, b)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  lst = [
    "iceman", "cinema", "leaf", "tree", "live",
    "Evil", "Silent", "listen", "good", "god"
  ]

  anagram(lst)

=>    
iceman cinema
live Evil
Silent listen
```

**追記**

itertools を使わない場合には以下の様になります。

```
def anagram(lst):
  l = len(lst)
  for i in range(l):
    for j in range(i+1, l):
      if sorted(lst[i].lower()) == sorted(lst[j].lower()):
        print(lst[i], lst[j])
```

Comment: 勉強になります！ちなみにこのitertoolsモジュールを使わずに書くことは可能でしょうか？